# ¿Por que no me funciona esta consulta sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

La columna primer_aviso es de tipo DATE, pongo una imagen de los registros ingresados hasta ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haciendo esta consulta:

```
SELECT primer_aviso FROM tabla_principal WHERE 'primer_aviso' < '2017-12-01'
```

¿No se supone me deberian aparecer solamente los registros que tengan fecha de antes del primero de diciembre de 2017? Porque me arroja 0 registros. Y la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT primer_aviso FROM tabla_principal WHERE 'primer_aviso' >= '2017-12-01'
```

¿No deberia mostrar los registros del primero de diciembre de 2017 en adelante? Porque me aparecen todos los registros de la tabla. Estos son los resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por que.

Comment: Debes quitar las comillas simples al nombre de la columna, lo puedes poner así: `SELECT primer_aviso FROM tabla_principal WHERE primer_aviso >= '2017-12-01'` al ponerle comillas jamás sabrá que es una columna de la tabla, sino un valor de cadena equivalente a `primer_aviso`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al poner el nombre de la columna entre comillas, lo que preguntas es si :

**La cadena `primer_aviso`** es `< '2017-12-01'`  o si la **cadena `primer_aviso`** es `>= '2017-12-01'`

Para hacer `SELECT` de la columna, debes quitar las comillas simples. Si a lo sumo quieres usar comillas, deben ser **estas** ``, no estas '...', no hacen la misma función, como podrás comprender.

Prueba así:

```
SELECT primer_aviso FROM tabla_principal WHERE primer_aviso < '2017-12-01'

SELECT primer_aviso FROM tabla_principal WHERE primer_aviso >= '2017-12-01'
```

O bien así:

Nótese que aquí puse todo (nombres de tablas y de columnas) con las comillas ``... cuestión de **uniformidad**. Por lo general funcionará de ambas formas.

```
SELECT `primer_aviso` FROM `tabla_principal` WHERE `primer_aviso` < '2017-12-01'

SELECT `primer_aviso` FROM `tabla_principal` WHERE `primer_aviso` >= '2017-12-01'
```

Comment: Uf, menuda tonteria la mia, muchas gracias!